# When saving `model.state_dict()` in Pytorch, what are saved and what are not?

Tags: pytorch

I am a bit confused about Pytorch's saving mechanism.

I have the following model:

```py
import torch

class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # This one is used in forward() directly
        self.fc_direct = torch.nn.Linear(100, 100)

        # This one is used in forward() indirectly
        self.fc_indirect = torch.nn.Linear(100, 100)

        # This one is not used at all
        self.fc_not_used = torch.nn.Linear(100, 100)

        # This one is used in forward()
        self.value_a = 100

        # This one is used in bar()
        self.value_b = 100

        # This one is not used at all
        self.value_c = 100

    def forward(self, x):
        self.value_a += 1
        return self.fc_direct(self.foo(x))

    def foo(self, x):
        return self.fc_indirect(x)

    def bar(self):
        self.value_b += 1

model = MyModel()
```

I have several different things in this model.

I'm not sure if I call `torch.save({'model_state' : model.state_dict()}, 'model.pt')` to save it and reload it, which will be saved, and which will not?

Comment: Only registered [`Parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html) will be saved. You can output the content of `model.state_dict()` to see all those parameters. Whether and how an instance attribute is used has no influence.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny All nn modules, and tensors wrapped like `nn.Parameter(tensor)` , assigned in `__init__()` will be automatically registered, am I right?

Comment: A modules state dict contains both the registered parameters **and** the registered buffers. Buffers are similar to parameters in that they are part of the state dict, but they are not returned by `Module.parameters()` and are not updated by the optimizer.

Comment: @landings Yes, wrapping in `nn.Parameter` will automatically register the parameter. To register a buffer use something like `self.register_buffer('value_a', torch.tensor(100))` in place of `self.value_a = 100`.

Comment: @jodag Hi, if I want to save some non-tensor things along with my model, for example, the name of the model, or the training start time, etc, what is the best way?